# qtip and html data in title="" is causing conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, double-quotes, qtip2

I'm trying to load html content into [visjs timeline](http://visjs.org) and using [qtip2](http://qtip2.com) to display a tooltip when a hyperlink inside a timeline is clicked. This tooltip needs to display html content, so it has "" in it, which causes a problem when its inserted into a title="". Normally i would be able to use a single quote in the title='<-html - content->' so it should be able to handle the quotes. But now i'm facing a problem, because i'm trying to do this from inside javascript which already uses a single quote from the javascript itself.

if i want to add a item to [visjs timeline](http://visjs.org), i need to insert new items to the timeline like this.

```
{id: <?php echo $key; ?>, group: <?php echo $aspects['group'][$key]; ?>, content: '<a title="<?php if(isset($aspects['interpretation'][$key])): echo $aspects['interpretation'][$key]; endif;?>" role="button"><?php echo $aspects['symbols'][$key]; ?></a>', start: new Date(<?php echo $aspects['dates']['start'][$key]['year']; ?>, <?php echo $aspects['dates']['start'][$key]['month'] - 1;?>, <?php echo $aspects['dates']['start'][$key]['day'];?>, <?php echo $aspects['dates']['start'][$key]['hour'];?>, <?php echo $aspects['dates']['start'][$key]['min'];?>), end: new Date(<?php echo $aspects['dates']['end'][$key]['year']; ?>,<?php echo $aspects['dates']['end'][$key]['month'] - 1; ?>, <?php echo $aspects['dates']['end'][$key]['day']; ?>, <?php echo $aspects['dates']['end'][$key]['hour']; ?>, <?php echo $aspects['dates']['end'][$key]['min']; ?> ) },
```

But as you can see, content:' href etc ' already uses a single quote. So how can i escape this html quotes so it doesn't cause a conflict? I tried things like title = \"  \" in the href, but i am not finding any solution yet to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before outputting your PHP variables.

Comment: Hmm something changed, but now the html content, seems to destroy the content because it has multiple lines.

Comment: The multiple lines aren't coming from htmlspecialchars but your vars.
I would recommend you to take a closer look at the documentation or check out the other answers if you want a js solution.
Besides you shouldnt evaluate if statements in your strings because as you see it gets messy very fast. Better evaluate them before and then just concatinate them. And it would really help if you post your code properly formatted.

Comment: I removed the linebreaks with str_replace, thanx for the help. Got it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [templating strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in JavaScript.

```
var string = `hello " and ' work in this string`;
```